# Usage of ETS R codes through RExcel macros in VBA

Tags: r, vba, rexcel

Issue:
Usage of ETS R codes through RExcel macros in VBA

Given below is my command code:

Rinterface.runrcodefromrange Range(“Sheet1!B2:D8”)

Following are the codes written in the given cell reference:

```
       #!rput   zz  'Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$22
       library(forecast)    
       zz <- ts(zz,freq=365,start=c(2009,1))
       etsz <- ets(zz,model='AAN')
       etszP <- forecast(etsz,h=34)
       write.table(etszP)
```

How can I import the output table at the end of the code from RExcel to Excel using Rexcel Macros?

Other option I have tried is:

Rinterface.getarray “etszP”, Range(“Sheet1!Z1”)
The output in this case is not in the desired format.